# Teams app created using SharePoint content url but not behaving as expected

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-teams

Created a new Teams app via the developer portal app within Teams. I had the same intent as a previously created Teams app that would allow our users to open an app in teams that would allow a SharePoint site to be easily accessible. The behavior difference is when the sharepoint site is available within the app and a link is pressed on the page, the previously created app keeps the experience in Teams. The newly created app opens the computer's default browser and displays the clicked link's page.

The app was created with the 1.16 manifest version.
The previously created app has the 1.14 manifest version.

I've tried analyzing the json manifest to ensure all other attributes are congruent. They are except for one attribute and that is the last line "resource":""}} . The previous app contains our org's sharepoint site prefix - "resource":"https://company1com.sharepoint.com/"}}. I attempted to insert that resource but the teams app admin console would not allow me to update the package once changed.

Comment: Hello @Matt - Could you please downloading the package locally and update the resource section and upload the custom package. reference link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/deploy-and-publish/apps-upload

Comment: I updated the resource section in the json manifest to match the previously created app and tried to both upload via Teams Admin Center as well as through the manage apps section of Teams. 

Teams Admin center Upload App option produced the following error - 
Mgmt.AppCatalog.LOBApp.Upload.BadRequest.Error

Manage Apps - Upload an App produced - Manifest parsing has failed.

Comment: Could you please share your manifest and tenant id with us at microsoftteamsdev@microsoft.com.

Comment: Certainly! Thanks for taking a look

Comment: We are not able to repro the issue, we are trying the same scenario as mentioned above. It is working fine from our end.
Microsoft Teams Version 1.6.00.24053 (64-bit). 
Could you please zip the app package from here then extract and upload.
[![enter image description here][1]][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1P4T.png

Comment: Just to confirm, for both app packages, the links selected DO NOT take you to a browser and stay within Teams?

Comment: Yes, it will open in teams only.
Please refer the below sample- https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/tab-channel-group/spfx